# jQuery trigger click on keypress

Tags: jquery

I have a "previous" and a "next" link on my website which I would like to trigger using the left and right arrow.

Can I actually trigger a link click with an arrow key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
var a1 = $('#a1')[0],
    a2 = $('#a2')[0];

$(window).keydown(function (e) {
    if ( e.which === 37 ) {
        window.location.href = a1.href;        
    } else if ( e.which === 39 ) {
        window.location.href = a2.href; 
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/SxeeT/2/

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    //this may not be necessary

    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       $('#previous').click();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       $('#next').click();
    }
});
```

Character codes:

37 - left

38 - up

39 - right

40 - down

Answer (score 4):

You can call the click event like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // not sure if you will need this but it should stop horizontal scrolling
    if(e.keyCode === 37) {
        $("#previous").click();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 39) {
        $("#next").click();
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7vzJ/9/) is a jsfiddle in action.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! The code WORKS but doesn't trigger the href link. What I'm really needing is to "click" a link and the website actually goes to href in the a tag. Is this possible?

Comment: Try that - I changed the divs to anchors.

Comment: `$("#previous").click();` only triggers the click handlers but `$("#previous")[0].click();` will simulate a click and handle both anchor tag `href` values and click handlers.  (the later is the native DOM `click` while the former is a jQuery method)